# find lat and lon in android app

Tags: android, android-activity, gps, android-location

i need to get the lat and lon in a activity.  In my oncreate method I tried the code below but im not getting anything when i try to print the Lat. What am I doing wrong. I have included  in the manifest file too. I need two strings with the value of Lat and lon

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

             LocationListener lis = new LocationListener(){

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("", "location " + location.getLatitude());

                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle extras) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }


            };


            manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, lis);
```

Comment: Please include your manifest.

Also, please clarify what "not getting anything" means. Are you not seeing any logging at all, or is the logging not showing the location?

Comment: I'd recommend using Google Play Services for location tracking:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html